# Using AWS CLI, how to add customize metadata headers to the all S3 objects at once?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using AWS CLI, to add cache control and expire header

I have used the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --metadata-directive REPLACE --expires 2034-01-01T00:00:00Z --acl public-read --cache-control max-age=2592000,public
```

But, due to this my existing tags got replaced and to some objects in my S3 bucket, they also had custom metadata header like `"x-amz-meta-s3b-last-modified:20170209T042854Z"`

So, now if I need to add it again. How can I do that?

Comment: That is what `--metadata-directive REPLACE` does... replace the metadata.  `--metadata-directive COPY` is used to preserve it.

Comment: R user: Quite a few people are editing your questions to make them more readable for future readers. In particular, when referring to yourself ("I"), please use a capital letter. It can be irritating to native English readers to see this in lower case, and does not give the impression that much effort has been expended on formulating a clear and well-researched question.